# kendo ui scheduler firing wrong events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use simple events which should fire an alert to tell me if something has happend. Unfortunately the only the event that is triggering is save and add. save is triggering whenever I resizeEnd or moveEnd, which doesn't make sense to me. move isn't even triggering nor is resize.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="scheduler"></div>
</div>
<script>
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
    startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 12:00 AM"),
    height: 600,
    allDaySlot: false,
    resize: function(e) {
        alert('resize');
    },
    resizeEnd: function(e) {
        alert('resizeEnd');
    },
    move: function(e) {
        alert('move');
    },
    moveEnd: function(e) {
        alert("moveEnd");
    },
    add: function(e) {
        alert("add");
    },
    save: function(e) {
        alert('save');
    },
    views: [
        "week",
        "month"
    ],
    dataSource: {
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "eventID",
                fields: {
                    eventID: { type: "number" },
                    title: { defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                    start: { type: "date" },
                    end: { type: "date" },
                    careGiverId: { nullable: true },
                    isAllDay: { type: "boolean" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    group: {
        resources: [ "care" ]
    },
    resources: [
        {
            field: "careGiverId",
            name: "care",
            dataSource: [
                { text: "Jeffery Dohmer (Care Giver 1)", value: 1, color: "#6eb3fa" },
                { text: "David Kaplan (Care Giver 2)", value: 2, color: "#6eb3fa" },
                { text: "Ben Dover (Care Giver 3)", value: 3, color: "#6eb3fa" }
            ],
            title: "Care"
        }
    ]

});
</script>
```

I've read the documentation and it seems like I'm doing everything right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine and all events are fired. I think that your problem is using `alert` for displaying messages from inside an event handler. Try using `console.log` instead or define someplace where to show the traces.

Comment: Man, I must have some real bad luck then, lol. I'll re-check my work, but I have used console.log before and it didn't really do much for me. Thanks for taking the time to check my work.

Comment: I've also realized that you need to use a recent version of Kendo UI tried with 2013.2.918 and works but not with 2013.2.716

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize that I the scheduler was so new. Do you think it will it work with the next major GPL release?

Comment: With next I would say definitely yes, this is what Kendo UI uses to do: between GPL releases they do patches and they provide them to paying customers, then they release it for everybody as GPL.